# Scene Builder does not display styles from css

Tags: javafx, styling, scenebuilder

I am using Java 11 (11.0.8) and Gradle 6.1

I am using the latest available Scene Builder 18.0.0 (as of 09.07.22). The Gluon website says: "You can use this Scene Builder version together with Java 11 and higher". Ok.

I use .fxml files in my application. Scene Builder doesn't see the styles from the .css files, but when I run the application, they are visible. I don't understand what could be the reason.

=Example=

This is what the Scene Builder
[shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw1m9.png)

When you start the application, you see this
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enI7g.png)

Here's what's in the .css file :

```
.memo{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
#memo{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Here is my .gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
}

group 'com.github'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "11.0.2"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls','javafx.fxml' ]
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

mainClassName = 'com.github.Main'
```

Button code from .fxml:

```
<Button id="memo" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="memo" stylesheets="@../css/input.css" text="111" />
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdmPX.png) is where the .css is

Comment: SceneBuilder ships with its own Java runtime, any other Java runtime you have installed is irrelevant.  SceneBuilder does not use Gradle, that is also irrelevant.  SceneBuilder only uses fxml and supporting resources such as fonts, images, css, etc when they are correctly referenced and the URLs can be resolved relative to their locations.  Custom Java conttrols can also be imported, but that is not common.

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out! After long hours. I gave you incomplete information. My .css file actually looked like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat Bold";
    src: url("/font/Montserrat-Bold.otf");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat Regular";
    src: url("/font/Montserrat-Regular.otf");
}
.memo{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
#memo{
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

As it turned out, the css file was not seen by Scene Builder because of these @font-face. I took this section when from an older version in which this apparently worked! I hope I helped someone. Thanks everyone!